# Google Big Query Error: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Row: 1 errors: 1

Tags: google-bigquery

[image]
I am trying to run a query on a 12 GB csv file loaded in Google big query, I cant run any query on the dataset. I am not sure if the dataset is loaded correctly. It shows as a table in the pane, but it is not present in the job history. Can anyone help on the same.

The dataset was loaded from a google storage bucket which has around 1.2MM records and 3728 variables

> Job ID: p-g-us-adv-x-dat-aia-proto-1:bquijob_b951879_1540d02c1a4

Comment: Pictures of code and errors are nowhere near as useful as the text of them. For example, the pictures can't be searched by future users who may otherwise find your question or answer helpful. Please [edit] with the relevant text, and a [mcve] that can demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 22):

Check your schema - it's possible that you forgot to include the schema for one of the columns - that's what happened to me!

Comment: This is what happened to my case, I think BQ should refine their error message to be more informative

Comment: Adding to your answer, This could happen in case of datatype mismatch too.

Answer (score 8):

To get more info on the errors try this from the CLI:

`>bq show -j  <jobid>`

It prints the status and/or detailed error information.

To list all the jobids:
`bq ls -j`

Answer (score 6):

job.errors contains detailed errors for the job.

This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, but you can see it in the source code: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/0.20.0/_modules/google/cloud/bigquery/job.html and ctrl+f for _AsyncJob.

So your wait_for_job code could look like this:

```
def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: So very helpful. Thank you Ben!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue following the [instructions in the GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#format).

It failed on the second `bq load`, but not the first.

I found that repeating the job in the BigQuery web interface selecting the `ignore unknown values` option.

I have not spotted any errors with the data yet, but just getting started looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick: If you use csv files with a header line and want to load with a defined schema, you need to add option `--skip_leading_rows=1` to submit command(example: `bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 --source_format=CSV ...`).

Without this option, Bigquery will parse your first row(header line) as an data row, may lead to TYPE MISMATCH ERROR (your defined schema of a column is FLOAT, but its column name is STRING, and `bq load` command parses your column name as a FLOAT value).

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error with no clue of the actual problem.

```
<https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/****/jobs/job_******?location=******> <{
reason: invalid message: Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 115;
errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.  }
```

Tried bq --format=prettyjson show -j => This also didn't gave any more clue.

I was trying to transfer data from a Database to Big Query using SAP BODS as the ETL Tool. To find the root cause I had to modify the ETL to transfer column by column i.e. I first transferred one column, then added 2nd, and so on. The transfer was successful for initial string columns. But when a FLOAT column came, the transfer gave the same error.

When checking the data I found values as .0345 in the decimal column in database. For values less than 1, 0 was removed before decimal which was causing error during transfer to Big Query.

To rectify, I had to apply to_decimal conversion of BODS.

```
to_decimal(column_name, '.', ',', 4)
```

"," is the thousand separator

"." is the decimal separator

4 specifies the nos allowed after decimal

**Note:** : I was also transferring records to Google Cloud Storage simultaneously and it was getting successful before conversion also. Also, when I manually used Cloud Storage file to populate the same BigQuery table, it was also working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Problem can also stem from DATETIME format. The correct format for the column is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S". Anything apart from this throws the above error.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're querying against a CSV file that hasn't been loaded into BigQuery, it is just being pointed to by a federated table that lives in Google Cloud Storage.

It looks like there were errors in the underlying CSV file:

```
Too many value in row starting at position:11398444388 in file:gs://syntheticpopulation-storage/Alldatamerged_Allgrps.csv
Too many value in row starting at position:9252859186 in file:gs://syntheticpopulation-storage/Alldatamerged_Allgrps.csv
...
```

Please let me know if this is enough to diagnose the issue. I believe you can see those messages as warnings on the query job if you look at the query history.

I've filed three bugs internally:

1. Poor grammar in the error message.
2. Error messages stemming from problems in federated tables are not diagnosable because they don't tell you what table has the problem.
3. Error messages from problems in federated tables aren't actionable in the UI, since the information about what went wrong is in the warning stream, which is not displayed.

Comment: Hi Jordan.. Thanks for the reply. How do I get this table loaded to the big query platform. Is it not loading because of the size(the table is correctly stored in the storage bucket- checked it). There couln't be any other reason I can think of since I have uploaded tables of size 5GB and the schema structure and the data types are correctly mentioned. Could you please suggest.

Comment: If a load job attempting to load this csv file fails, can you provide the job id of the failing load job and error message?

Comment: Added the image/error(loading error) in the Jordan's comment

Comment: See loading data in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery

Comment: @JordanTigani How is the position helpful here? It would be easy to get some lines of data that is failing. Very simple use case is taking unnecessary amount of data because of low quality error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known bug @google. The already made the fix, but did not push it in production.
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=621

Answer (score 0):

Before passing my elements into Bigquery using **beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(...)** I was passing my elements through **beam.Map(print)**. After removing this I got no errors and files loaded onto my BigQuery.