# Bigquery CSV file load fail

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, export-to-csv

google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.

I am trying to run Python script that loads the data into csv but getting this error. can anyone explain me this error

```
   import csv
#Imports the Google Cloud BigQuery client library
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import Dataset
from google.cloud.bigquery import Table
from google.cloud.bigquery import LoadJobConfig
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField

filename = 'events.csv'
idNeeded=0
#Instantiates a client
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

#Runs a query from BigQuery
def runBigQueryQuery( query, filename, idNeeded ):

  if idNeeded == 1:  
    i = 1
    query_job = bigquery_client.query(query)

    results = query_job.result()

    with open (filename, 'w', newline='') as f: #Create CSV file
      write = csv.writer(f,dialect='excel',lineterminator='\n')
      try:
        for row in results:
          print('{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{} '.format(row.EventId,
row.ScheduleId,
row.Date, 
row.TimeFrom, 
row.Description,
row.TimeTo, 
row.ResourceId, 
row.EmployeeId, 
row.MovementTypeId, 
row.Capacity, 
row.CanBook, 
row.NonMemberFlag, 
row.MemberAmount, 
row.NonMemberAmount, 
row.Attendance))
          write.writerow([i,row.EventId,
row.ScheduleId,
row.Date, 
row.TimeFrom, 
row.Description,
row.TimeTo, 
row.ResourceId, 
row.EmployeeId, 
row.MovementTypeId, 
row.Capacity, 
row.CanBook, 
row.NonMemberFlag, 
row.MemberAmount, 
row.NonMemberAmount, 
row.Attendance]) #write Rows to CSV
          i = i+1
      except AttributeError as error:
        print('An error occured: {0}'.format(error))


  else:
    query_job = bigquery_client.query(query)

    results = query_job.result()

    with open (filename, 'w', newline='') as f: #Create CSV file
      write = csv.writer(f,dialect='excel',lineterminator='\n')
      try:
        for row in results:
          print('{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{} '.format( row.EventId,
row.ScheduleId,
row.Date, 
row.TimeFrom, 
row.Description,
row.TimeTo, 
row.ResourceId, 
row.EmployeeId, 
row.MovementTypeId, 
row.Capacity, 
row.CanBook, 
row.NonMemberFlag, 
row.MemberAmount, 
row.NonMemberAmount, 
row.Attendance))
          write.writerow([row.EventId,
row.ScheduleId,
row.Date, 
row.TimeFrom, 
row.Description,
row.TimeTo, 
row.ResourceId, 
row.EmployeeId, 
row.MovementTypeId, 
row.Capacity, 
row.CanBook, 
row.NonMemberFlag, 
row.MemberAmount, 
row.NonMemberAmount, 
row.Attendance]) #write Rows to CSV
      except AttributeError as error:
        print('An error occured: {0}'.format(error))

  return

#Creates a dataset in BigQuery
def createDataset(datasetname):
  dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(datasetname)

  dataset = Dataset(dataset_ref)
  dataset.location = 'US'

  dataset = bigquery_client.create_dataset(dataset)

  return

def getDataset(datasetname):

  dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(datasetname)

  return dataset

def createTable(tablename, global_dataset_ref):

  schema = [
    #Enter Schema here.
    # SchemaField('url', 'STRING', mode='required'),
    # SchemaField('views', 'INTEGER', mode='required')
  ]

  table_ref = global_dataset_ref.table(tablename)

  table = Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
  table = bigquery_client.create_table(table)

  assert table.table_id == tablename

  return

def getTable(tablename, global_dataset_ref):

  table_ref = global_dataset_ref.table(tablename)
  table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)

  # print(table.table_id)
  print(table.schema)
  # print(table.description)
  # print(table.num_rows)

  return table


def getTableSchema(tablename, global_dataset_ref):

  table_ref = global_dataset_ref.table(tablename)
  table = bigquery_client.get_table(table_ref)

  schema = table.schema

  return schema

def loadDataFromCSV(tablename, global_dataset_ref, filename):

  schema = getTableSchema(tablename, global_dataset_ref)

  table_ref = global_dataset_ref.table(tablename)

  load_config = LoadJobConfig()
  load_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
  load_config.schema = schema
  load_config.autodetect = True
  load_config.allow_quoted_newlines = True

  with open (filename, 'rb') as readable:
      job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(readable, table_ref, location='US', job_config=load_config)

  job.result()

  print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(job.output_rows, global_dataset_ref, table_ref.table_id)) 

  return

# Testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
  datasetname = 'Data_Layer'
  tablename = 'Events'

  sqlquery = '''SELECT 
  null as EventId,
  sc.scheduleid AS ScheduleId,
  NULL AS Description,
  sc.scheduledatefrom AS Date,
  sc.timestart AS TimeFrom,
  sc.timeduration AS TimeTo,
  r.resourceid AS ResourceId,
  sp.employeeid AS EmployeeId,
  NULL AS MovementTypeId,
  r.configheight AS Capacity,
  CASE
    WHEN st.schedulestatus IN (1,  3) THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
  END CanBook,
  CASE
    WHEN sv.nonmembermayenroll = TRUE THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
  END NonMemberFlag,
  COALESCE(ProgramPrice.pricemember,
    ServicePrice.pricemember,
    0) AS MemberAmount,
  COALESCE(ProgramPrice.pricenonmember,
    ServicePrice.pricenonmember,
    0) AS NonMemberAmount,
  'N/A' AS Attendance
FROM
  AloomaTest.SCSESSIONS s
LEFT JOIN
  AloomaTest.SCSESSION_PROVIDERS sp
ON
  sp.sessionid = s.sessionid
LEFT JOIN
  AloomaTest.SCSESSION_RESOURCES sr
ON
  sr.sessionid = s.sessionid
LEFT JOIN
  AloomaTest.SCSCHEDULES sc
ON
  sc.scheduleid = s.scheduleid
LEFT JOIN
  AloomaTest._SCSCHEDULESTATUS ST
ON
  ST.schedulestatus = sc.schedulestatus
LEFT JOIN
  AloomaTest.SCRESOURCES r
ON
  r.resourceid = sr.resourceid
LEFT JOIN
  AloomaTest.SCSERVICES sv
ON
  sv.serviceid = sc.serviceid
LEFT JOIN
  AloomaTest.SCPROGREG_SEMCOURSES semc
ON
  semc.serviceid = sc.serviceid
  AND semc.semesterid = sc.semesterid
LEFT JOIN
  AloomaTest.SCPROGREG_PRICES ProgramPrice
ON
  ProgramPrice.scheduleid = sc.scheduleid
LEFT JOIN
  AloomaTest.SCPROGREG_PRICES ServicePrice
ON
  ServicePrice.semcourseid = semc.semcourseid
WHERE
  COALESCE(ProgramPrice.feetypeid,
    0) = 0
  AND COALESCE(ServicePrice.feetypeid,
    0)= 0
    and  sc.scheduleid in(31207,
25936,
5761094,
832794,
9825,
17912)
'''

  #createDataset(datasetname) #Successfully tested this code 2018-09-24
global_dataset_ref = getDataset(datasetname) #Successfully tested this code 2018-09-24

  #createTable(tablename, global_dataset_ref) #Successfully tested this code 2018-09-24
getTable(tablename, global_dataset_ref) #Successfully tested this code 2018-09-24

runBigQueryQuery(sqlquery,filename,idNeeded) #Successfully tested this code 2018-09-24

loadDataFromCSV(tablename, global_dataset_ref,filename) #Successfully tested this code 2018-09-24
```

sample data

```
,25936,2009-06-01 18:30:00,1110,M1PO - M1 PT Full,60,,254,,,1,0,0,0,N/A
,17912,2009-04-22 06:15:00,375,Pil Ptnr - Pilates Partner,60,47,398,,10,1,1,0,0,N/A
,31207,2009-06-22 19:00:00,1140,D390-2 - 1 1/2 Hour Massage,90,107,548,,20,0,0,0,0,N/A
,5761094,2018-10-05 00:00:00,1140,Fr 7:00-9:00p Adult Paddle Mixer,120,583,2349,,20,0,1,20,50,N/A
,5761094,2018-10-05 00:00:00,1140,Fr 7:00-9:00p Adult Paddle Mixer,120,591,2349,,20,0,1,20,50,N/A
,5761094,2018-10-05 00:00:00,1140,Fr 7:00-9:00p Adult Paddle Mixer,120,585,2349,,20,0,1,20,50,N/A
,5761094,2018-10-05 00:00:00,1140,Fr 7:00-9:00p Adult Paddle Mixer,120,584,2349,,20,0,1,20,50,N/A
,832794,2012-02-21 14:30:00,870,Comp Member One/One,60,,2963,,,1,0,0,0,N/A
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the code you're using... it's hard to debug as of now.

Comment: Just added the code

Comment: As @neil said its probably data related my advice try to upload the file from the UI it will help you troubleshoot your problem (header issue, wrong schem,  data escaping etc)

Comment: @Tamir I have loaded the sample data too

Comment: Hope this can help https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5624, Also as mentioned try the UI to upload your data.

Comment: does your CSV have a header? this can fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54121978/10801700


which function in your code is throwing the error?

also check if the CSV is well-formed: https://www.thoughtspot.com/6-rules-creating-valid-csv-files

Comment: I got the fix it was DATA type error

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that there is only 1 row in your CSV, you might be missing new lines while making it.