# 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 29274; errors: 1

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery

I want to load data to bigQuery using python, but I get the following error:

> 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 29274; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.

I have tried step like this link [CSV Table Encountered Too Many Errors, Giving Up](https://support.supermetrics.com/support/solutions/articles/19000099709-csv-table-encountered-too-many-errors-giving-up) but I have not permission to view feature `Transfer` in google cloud platform.

I have no idea where the error happens and how to solve it?

As a reference, I find the solution in this link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40853018/10460271) but can not understand.

Comment: What is in the `errors[]` collection?

Comment: that is not show where `error[]` collection, how can i know ?

Comment: You can try to load the data via the webUI and check the error[] object from there or check the Job History for more information from the left side top menu

Comment: Agree with @TamirKlein here, instead of writing to BigQuery writ your data out to a .csv then upload this manually. Checking the logs should guide you to the problem, which is likely a null value or some unexpected character around row 29274.

Comment: If you are using Python code then you have something like `load_job = client.load_table_from_uri....` , you should be able to access the `errors[]` collection like `load_job.errors`.

Comment: i got the error `Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 16, but line starting at position:1137363 contains only 11 columns.
` and 1 error again `It looks like you are appending to an existing table with autodetect enabled. Disabling autodetect may resolve this.
` how that means ? i should add 1 more column and unable auto-detect schema ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary for you to open a ticket directly with Google Cloud Platform   Support. Before that you can follow this [article](https://support.supermetrics.com/support/solutions/articles/19000099709-csv-table-encountered-too-many-errors-giving-up) to try and inspect the error collection.

But in order to do this you need the appropriate permissions for the Transfer service(otherwise one of your admins must do this).

You may be able to assign the needed permissions, depending on the roles already assigned to your account. The role needed is "BigQuery Data Transfer Service Agent". This [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) explains how to assign roles to a member.

Comment: i got the error via job history like that  `Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 14, but line starting at position:546999 contains only 10 columns. `