# Where can I find the error stream in python + pandas + big query?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload data to Bigquery and I always encounter this problem:

```
BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.
```

And I'm using pandas-gbq so I get other error (same thing):

```
GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.
```

The thing is I saw people talking about running in terminal with a jobID, how do I get that job id if I'm using Jupyter?

Or is there an easier way to debug this problem without slicing the dataframe and uploading part by part to see what is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586472/google-big-query-error-csv-table-encountered-too-many-errors-giving-up-row-1

Comment: Also this is relevant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100812/bigquery-where-can-i-find-the-error-stream

Comment: Thanks Ahmet, I feel this doesn't work because they are using directly bq in terminal or jobs in python, my case is with pandas-gbq.

Comment: Could you please attach the schema of the BQ table? You can copy the schema from cloud console -> BigQuery -> Select the table -> Schema tab -> copy the table and paste into excel sheet. Additionally, please share the sample data you are trying to load into BQ.

Comment: I fixed by uploading column by column but I want to know if there is an easier way to debug this kind of problems with pandas_gbq. Thanks!