# What does this error mean: Required column value for column index: 8 is missing in row starting at position: 0

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm attempting to upload a CSV file (which is an output from a BCP command) to BigQuery using the gcloud CLI BQ Load command. I have already uploaded a custom schema file. (was having major issues with Autodetect).

One resource suggested this could be a [datatype mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586472/google-big-query-error-csv-table-encountered-too-many-errors-giving-up-row-1). However, the table from the SQL DB lists the column as a decimal, so in my schema file I have listed it as FLOAT since decimal is not a supported data type.

I couldn't find any documentation for what the error means and what I can do to resolve it.

Comment: Hi OP, can you provide the BigQuery command you are using to upload and also the CSV file input you are trying to load? This is to properly replicate your use case

Comment: @ScottB here is the command I'm using `bq load --source_format=CSV acumatica.SOShipment C:\BCPDemo\SOShipment.tsv`

Comment: FWIW, I've also saved as CSV and am encountering the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does this error mean?** It means, in this context, a value is REQUIRED for a given column index and one was not found. (By the way, columns are usually 0 indexed, meaning a fault at column index 8 is most likely referring to column number 9)

This can be caused by myriad of different issues, of which I experienced two.

1. **Incorrectly categorizing NULL columns as NOT NULL**. After exporting the schema, in JSON, from SSMS, I needed to clean it
   up for BQ and in doing so I assigned `IS_NULLABLE:NO` to
   `MODE:NULLABLE` and `IS_NULLABLE:YES` to `MODE:REQUIRED`. These
   values should've been reversed. This caused the error because there
   were NULL columns where BQ expected a *REQUIRED* value.
2. **Using the wrong delimiter** The file I was outputting was not only comma-delimited but also tab-delimited. I was only able to validate this by using the Get Data tool in Excel and importing the data that way, after which I saw the error for tabs inside the cells.

After outputting with a pipe ( | ) delimiter, I was finally able to successfully load the file into BigQuery without any errors.

Comment: Hi OP, since you have already fixed your main question, you may accept your posted answer to help the community that may encounter the same use case in the future. For your new error, this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#view_job_details_2 documentation might help wherein you may inspect the job using the `job ID` to get details or hints for the error. In any case, you may post your new error as a new question for the community to help you resolve it. When posting a new question, please ensure to include the actual command you are running and sample data if possible.